How to find Euler angles for orientation of Single crystals with respect to Lab Frame?
I have a monoclinic C2 space group single crystal sample glued to a tenon plate. I know the surface normal direction and the edge plan of the crystal. Also, I know the XY plane of the tenon plate. How can I get the Euler angles to relate the frames of the sample and the tenon plate (Lab frame)?
(I have also attached a picture of the crystal on the plate. The circle in the picture marks the surface normal direction (1 0 -2) and the edge plane is (0 1 0). The blue vectors represent the frame of the tenon plate) ​
So far, I have read research papers related to this issue. But either the crystal is not monoclinic or the rotation of the crystal is around one of the axis of crystal. This pair is called axes/angle pair
If there is any article or software that can help with this information then it will be useful.

